# Composer shows transport exception while installing package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I wanted to install Guzzle HTTP package for my Laravel 5.3 project.

But when I ran the specific install command, composer shows the following:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "http://packagist.org/p/cordoval/hamcrest-php%249e26dffac4ed896eb042373003ee127ad49377842601ba5bd833d00e135a3c62.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Tried `composer diagnose` and checked that all ok. Also tried `composer self-update` but that's no help, too.

Comment: can you post your composer diagnose results ?

Comment: ```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to force HTTPS for all resources by running `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after adding the following code at the end of composer.json, it worked!

"repositories": [
        {
             "type": "composer", 
             "url": "https://packagist.org"
        },
        { "packagist": false }
    ]